# Как открыть другую форму в С#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Форма авторизации. При вводе правильного пароля.
Должна открываться другая форма (FilmsControlForm)
Но вместо этого... Помогите исправить..

> Ошибка    1   не содержит конструктор, который
>   принимает 1 аргументов

Comment: Уберите this из конструктора

Comment: ...если он там не нужен. Если нужен - добавьте конструктор, принимающий форму в качестве параметра.

Comment: @tym32167 открывается пустая форма... а мне надо FilmsControlForm

Comment: @Zufir как его добавить? напишите...

Comment: Если вы не знаете, нужен ли он там, значит он вам не нужен, смело убирайте

Comment: у вас открывается `FilmsControlForm`, но она пустая. Видимо, с ней что то ещё надо сделать. Что именно - вам никто не подскажет, так как этот тип не стандартный.

Comment: а в FilmsControlForm точно что-то есть?

Comment: Не заставляйте людей гадать. Подготовьте [воспроизводимый пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

либо:

```
FilmsControlForm FilmsControlForm = new FilmsControlForm();
```

Или же переопределять конструктор

Comment: копипастить ответы выше не надо!

Comment: Плагиатор однако 

Comment: Здесь нет других ответов. А собирать в ответ предложения из комментариев не запрещено и даже хорошо, ибо ответ лучше виден посетителям вопроса.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это было бы хорошо, но во время публикации этого ответа в комментариях уже была инфа, что этот метод не помогает. То есть, по сути, ответ был заведомо бесполезен.

Answer (score 0):

Тут два варианта действия:
 1. Изменить показанный код
 2. В конструкторе формы создать инициализатор
Первый вариант:
код

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (maskedTextBox1.Text == "123")
 {
     FilmsControlForm FilmsControlForm = new FilmsControlForm(this);
     FilmsControlForm.Show();
    this.Hide();
 }
}
```

заменить на

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (maskedTextBox1.Text == "123")
{
    FilmsControlForm FilmsControlForm = new FilmsControlForm();// убрать this
    FilmsControlForm.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
}
```

Второй вариант:

```
public class FilmsControlForm:Form
{
  Form loginForm;
  public FilmsControlForm(Form CurrentForm)
  {
      loginForm =CurrentForm;
  }
}
```

При этом, предпочтительнее первый вариант.

Comment: прочтите комментарии. прежде чем давать "правильный ответ"

Comment: @amer3 Поправил, что-бы было более ясно

Comment: @akim от смены ника, вы выиграете немного.

Answer (score -1):

Вы пытаетесь инициализировать форму через констуркор с одним параметром (принимающая один аргумент, в даном примере this):

```
FilmsControlForm FilmsControlForm = new FilmsControlForm(this);
```

Ваша ошибка говорит что такого констурктора не найдено, т.е. либо используйте конструктор без параметров, либо создайте с одним (в FilmsControlForm):

```
public FilmsControlForm(object obj) // либо что там хотите передать? Form?
{
   InitializeComponent();
   //some code
}
```